# What does b=a->b means in a class of list?

Tags: c++, list

In a class of list what does b=a->b means?

The example i'm reading is a destructor to the list, and in its "while" cycle it has this operation.

```
Clistint::~Clistint(){ 
  Clist *actual, *next; 
  if(head!=NULL){ 
    actual=head; 
    while(actual!=NULL){ 
      next=actual->next; 
      delete actual; 
      actual=next; 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Which part is confusing you? The arrow?

Comment: More code would be great ?

Comment: Maybe you're confusing `b` to be the same as `->b` because they are named the same. From what I can gather this expression lets you traverse the list, maybe getting the next or the previous. But, I'm just speculating. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT** (now that you posted your code)

```
next=actual->next; 
delete actual; 
actual=next;
```

That would just set `actual` to `actual.next`. You can't just do

```
actual=actual->next;
```

Because that would be a memory leak (you would never delete the old `actual`). Also, you can't just do

```
next=actual.next;
```

Because `actual` is a pointer. Therefore you must get the thing it points to, like

```
next=(*actual).next;
```

But the `->` operator does exactly that, so you can just do

```
next=actual->next; // means the same thing as "next=(*actual).next;"
```

**(original post)**

It means the same as

```
b = (*a).b;
```

It will set the local variable `b` to the value of pointer `a`'s `b`. For example:

```
MyClass *a = new MyClass;
// do stuff with *a
int b;
b = a -> b; // gets the `b` value of `a` (assuming MyClass has a public int b)
            // same as "b = (*a).b;"
```

Answer (score 2):

`a` is a pointer to a struct or a class, and `a->b` is something in that struct or class, presumably a variable.  There is also a local scope variable called `b` that is being assigned the value of the `b` in struct `a`.  Without seeing complete code it's hard to say more.

Comment: I have to create a destructor to the list. The code i'm reading is:
[code]Clistint::~Clistint(){

Clist *actual, *next;

if(head!=NULL){
actual=head;
while(actual!=NULL){
next=actual->next;
delete actual;
actual=next;
}
}
}[/code]

Comment: That would be a pointer to an object, not a pointer to a `class` or `struct`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `=` and `->` are a basic built-in operators of C++ language. They are inherited from C. The meaning of these operators you can find in any book on C or C++.

Secondly, in C++ both `=` and `->` are overloadable operators, which means that the exact meaning of `b = a->b` cannot be determined without knowing what `a` is and what `b` is.